# Spark Streaming with Hadoop configuration object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

StreamingContext - fileStream is overloaded to take Hadoop configuration object also but it seems not working.

code snippet from Spark source code:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.scala

```
def fileStream[K: ClassTag,V: ClassTag,F <: NewInputFormat[K, V]: ClassTag] (directory: String): InputDStream[(K, V)] = 
{ new FileInputDStream[K, V, F](this, directory) }

def fileStream[K: ClassTag,V: ClassTag,F <: NewInputFormat[K, V]: ClassTag] (directory: String, filter: Path => Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean): InputDStream[(K, V)] = 
{ new FileInputDStream[K, V, F](this, directory, filter, newFilesOnly) }

def fileStream[K: ClassTag,V: ClassTag,F <: NewInputFormat[K, V]: ClassTag] (directory: String,filter: Path => Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean, conf: Configuration): InputDStream[(K, V)] = 
{ new FileInputDStream[K, V, F](this, directory, filter, newFilesOnly, Option(conf)) }
```

code snippet:
works fine

```
val windowDStream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](args(0), (x: Path) => true, true);
```

Compilation error:

```
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration;
    val windowDStream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](args(0), (x: Path) => true, true,conf);
```

error:

```
overloaded method value fileStream with alternatives: (directory: String,filter: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path ⇒ Boolean,newFilesOnly: Boolean)(implicit evidence$9: scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable], implicit evidence$10: scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text], implicit evidence$11: scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)] <and> (directory: String)(implicit evidence$6: scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable], implicit evidence$7: scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.apache.hadoop.io.Text], implicit evidence$8: scala.reflect.ClassTag[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)] cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path ⇒ Boolean, Boolean, org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using Spark 1.2 or older. If you change from master to the 1.2 branch, you will see that this overload does not exist. In fact, `FileInputDStream` itself did not accept this as a constructor argument until 1.3 either

Comment: Yes we are using Spark 1.2. Is there any work around to pass the hadoop configuration object to custom input format?

Comment: No, not without merging it into 1.2. It seems like an innocent enough change that you could possibly create a PR for, though. The codepath in 1.2 is static and doesn't read from any conf.